# Volume integration over a region

Tags: real-analysis, integration

If $E_1$ is a region in the first octant that is bounded by the spheres $x^2+y^2+z^2=4$, $x^2+y^2+z^2=9$ and the plane $y=\frac{x}{\sqrt{3}}$, what is
$$\int\int\int_{E_1} xdV?$$
I don't really have an idea how to handle this problem.

Comment: What have you already done, did you draw the corresponding solid ?

Comment: @MohamadMisto yes I have, but how does that help?

Comment: Use spherical coordinates, bound $2\le r \le3$ and $0\le\theta\le90$ and $30\le\phi\le90$. $\phi$ between 30 and 90 due to the plane that cuts the two spheres making an angle 30 with the $x$ axis.

Comment: Which side of the plane is interesting? From 0 to 30 degrees or from 30 degrees to 90 degrees???

Comment: @zoli All that I know is that the region is in the first octant, so $x,y,z\geq 0$

Comment: Nothing else is given, i hope thats what you were looking for

Comment: Then try to solve the problem base on the comments of Mohamed and my humble drawing. Chose the red or the green domain. But when submit your solution don't forget to mention that it was your choice that you had to make for there was no information on it.

Comment: @TonyStrong: I edited my post. I added another figure to help you.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

This image may help (together with the comments above...)

[image]

Use either the red or the grey area..

I attach the following figure to help visualize the domain of integration:
[image]

The grey cylindrical surface divides the volume into two volumes over which the boundaries are very different.

Comment: its unclear in the question if $\phi$ varies from 0 $\rightarrow$ 30 or from 30 $\rightarrow$ 90, right ?

Comment: @MohamadMisto Yes, to be hones I did not notice the ambiguity. OK. Let' ask the OP.